# ModulNotFoundError but Requirement already satisfied

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try running "import pandas as pd" it showns a ModulNotFoundError:No module named 'pandas'
But when I try writing pip install pandas in terminal it comes out like Requirement already satisfied.

Really stuck here, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may have different python environments. The problem was solved for me by selecting another python environment (Conda in my case). [image]

Answer (score 0):

[This is where the kernel is located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVvH5.png)

Change the kernel to conda from here, It could be that you are using your local python environment instead of conda and all packages you are installing are being installed in conda and not globally.

If changing the kernel doesn't fix it then try changing the interpreter, press ctrl + Shift + P and select the interpreter.

for more information on interpreter visit:
[https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#:~:text=To%20select%20a%20specific%20environment,Ctrl%2BShift%2BP](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#:%7E:text=To%20select%20a%20specific%20environment,Ctrl%2BShift%2BP)).

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Visual Studio Code, restart it after installing any library with it open. If the error persists, do `pip install pandas` on both the vs code terminal and cmd.

Comment: With this done it still shows the same error

Comment: Now it's also givig: Import "pandas" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource

Comment: 1. Did you try to run the code from cmd? 2. Are you using the global python environment?